# Summing Values by Given Date Segments

Tags: r, date, sum

**What I'd like is to sum segments of values that fall within the same time frame**. Any value that occurs after **6 hours** of the previous value, I want in a new segment. I'd also like to calculate the **# of hours in each segment** as well as the maximum and average value per segment.

Here's the example data:

```
Date <- c("1954-10-07", "1954-10-07", "1954-10-07", "1954-10-07", "1954-10-07", "1954-10-07", "1954-10-11", "1954-10-11", "1954-10-11", "1954-10-12", "1954-10-13")
Time <- c("0:00", "1:00", "4:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "9:00","10:00", "11:00", "23:00", "0:00")
DateTime <- paste(Date, Time)
Value <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.02, 0.2, 1.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.05)
df <- data.frame(Date, Time, DateTime, Value)

df
Date       Time     DateTime      Value
1954-10-07  0:00  1954-10-07 0:00  0.10
1954-10-07  1:00  1954-10-07 1:00  0.20
1954-10-07  4:00  1954-10-07 4:00  0.10
1954-10-07 13:00 1954-10-07 13:00  0.02
1954-10-07 14:00 1954-10-07 14:00  0.20
1954-10-07 15:00  1954-10-07 15:00  1.10
1954-10-11  9:00  1954-10-11 9:00  0.20
1954-10-11 10:00 1954-10-11 10:00  0.30
1954-10-11 11:00 1954-10-11 11:00  0.40
1954-10-12 23:00 1954-10-12 23:00  0.10
1954-10-13  0:00  1954-10-13 0:00  0.05
```

Desired output:

```
IntervalStart      IntervalEnd    ValueSum  ValueMax  ValueMedian  HoursinSegment
1954-10-07 0:00  1954-10-07 4:00    0.4       0.2        0.1           4
1954-10-07 13:00 1954-10-07 14:00   1.32      1.10       0.2           3
1954-10-11 9:00  1954-10-11 10:00   0.5       0.30       0.25          1
1954-10-12 23:00 1954-10-13 0:00    0.15      0.1        0.75          1
```

The trick I think is in the time stamps I think, because some values fall in the following day, but are still within 6 hours of the previous value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you are looking for:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,DateTime := as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s:00", DateTime))]

df[, Grp := cumsum(c(0, difftime(DateTime[-1], head(DateTime, -1), units = "h")) > 6)]

df[,.(Start = min(DateTime),
      End = max(DateTime),
      Min = min(Value),
      Max = max(Value),
      Median = median(Value),
      Span = difftime(max(DateTime), min(DateTime), "h")),
   by = "Grp"]
#    Grp               Start                 End  Min Max Median    Span
# 1:   0 1954-10-07 00:00:00 1954-10-07 04:00:00 0.10 0.2  0.100 4 hours
# 2:   1 1954-10-07 13:00:00 1954-10-07 15:00:00 0.02 1.1  0.200 2 hours
# 3:   2 1954-10-11 09:00:00 1954-10-11 11:00:00 0.20 0.4  0.300 2 hours
# 4:   3 1954-10-12 23:00:00 1954-10-13 00:00:00 0.05 0.1  0.075 1 hours
```

---

- `setDT(df)[,DateTime := as.POSIXct(...` converts `df` to a `data.table`, and converts the `DateTime` column to `POSIXct`
- `df[, Grp := cumsum(c(0, difftime(...` creates grouping IDs based on the condition you described above, i.e. when a `DateTime[i] - DateTime[i - 1]` is greater than 6 hours, a new grouping begins
- `df[,.(Start = min(DateTime), ...` calculates the aggregates for each `Grp`

Comment: Thanks! This is great, and works with the data above, but not with my larger, real dataset. It seems to cut the time off of the end of the start and end dates, and the Span variable just says "0 secs" for everything. Could it be something with my date formatting? I'm using `x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: This won't work with a `Date` field because that class does not store information on the hour component of a timestamp. You will need to use a `POSIXct` type, which is why I am using `as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s:00", DateTime))` above.

Comment: Ah, I see. What is the best way to format my Date column using `POSITXct` so that it is not an unambiguous format? That is the error I receive if I do not define it. My dates are organized m/d/y

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the Date column?

Comment: The data is just formatted that way when I pull it in, with a Date and Time column, so I combine them into DateTime in R. This is the error I get without defining: "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to generate that error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129640/discussion-between-kslayerr-and-nrussell).

Comment: I am not getting an error in any command using the package. Have you seen this before? `Error in `:=`(DateTime, as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s:00", DateTime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %T")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: Make sure the object you are using that with is a `data.table`. Try `setDT(object_name)` before that command.

Comment: Thanks! Figured out. I am now having a strange thing happen, where when I run your first line `x[,DateTime := as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s:00", DateTime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %T")]`, there are 7 instances where `DateTime` returns `NA`. They are all at times 2:00, but otherwise no reason why it should be happening.

Comment: `> x[5282,]
        Date Time Rainfall       DateTime
1: 4/26/1959 2:00   0.0109 4/26/1959 2:00
> x[,DateTime := as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s:00", DateTime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %T")]
> x[5282,]
        Date Time Rainfall DateTime
1: 4/26/1959 2:00   0.0109     <NA>`

Comment: I think those times occur exactly when daylight savings is applied. Try changing the `Time` value to something like `1:59` for those rows.

Comment: Wow, super intuitive! That's the issue, and now all rows are flowing and working nicely. Thank you again.

Comment: Last question I promise! Best way to export the output to csv??

Comment: Probably `data.table::fwrite(x, "/path/to/file.csv")`.